# Tunneling traffic and code execution to Citrix VDI

Tags: python, citrix

I know it's possible to open .ica file from python and interact with it by GUI. But it's possible to use the established VDI session to tunnel all the rest of the code execution to be done as if it's done on the VDI session. This will make VDI-only portals accessible from within my code.

Something like creating a SOCKS sever and bind a local port to it.

I heard about a third party library called (pyica) but never found it.

If that is possible, how to make sure the activity is also logged like the GUI for the sys admins ?

Thanks